# Dashboard controls in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, dashboard

I am working on a WinForm based applications(Yes I don't know WPF) and want's a dashboard like  panels in it. Picture given below [image]

Each panel will have a title and records from Database and some action controls. How could this be achieved? I don't want to use GridControl as I don't want to show Excel like spreadsheet here. How could this be achieved?

Comment: You could inherit from `UserControl` and roll your own layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx), possibly coupled with an automatic layout panel like [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).

Simply speaking, you would create a `UserControl` with whatever properties and events you require (i.e. in your example you might have a `Title` property and a `Data` property), and any events you need to respond to (e.g. you might have a button that you provide a wrapper event for). Then you can add the control to your existing form as you would any other standard control.

As far as displaying data in list form goes, one suggestion is to use a `Panel` and dynamically add `Label`s to it. Another idea could be just a simple `Label` with line breaks in the `Text`.

Comment: but how to display data in List form? I don't want to use Excel Sheet like DataGrid

Comment: @Volatil3 Edited with a couple of suggestions. Not sure what exactly you're looking for but try some experiments.

Comment: I have attached screen shot, the lines shows the data coming from database, actually list of records.

Comment: @Volatil3 You can probably get away with a panel and with labels added from code.